# Can I add an autoincrementing primary key to a SQLite table that already exists?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table in SQLite:

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries (
  name VARCHAR(255),
  population INT
);
```

I now want to add a new [auto-incrementing](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), primary key column.

I basically want to do this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE countries ADD COLUMN id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT;
```

But when running this query, I always get this error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: Cannot add a PRIMARY KEY column
```

Does anyone know whether that's even possible with SQLite?

Comment: I believe you will have to create a new table with an auto int primary key as you want. make a select into in this table and then rename the table as you want

Comment: You can't add a new column which is PRIMARY KEY. @apomene's suggestion is a good solution. Or you can use your current table's `rowid` column which exists already. Just do a `select rowid, name, population from countries`. You can find more here: https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

Comment: @forpas Thanks a lot for your comment. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @nburk it's fine. This is something mentioned several times in SO